# `delete` all `USER` except `Administrator`

Tags: sql-server, syntax-error

I am trying to write a simple SQL script to delete all `USER` except `Administrator`.

```
DELETE * 
FROM [Project].[dbo].[User] 
EXCEPT USER Administrator
```

- `[Project].[dbo].[User]`  Table name
- `USER` className
- `Administrator` element which I want to keep

Does anyone know where I am making a mistake?

Comment: You don't say what type of database you're using. Have you checked the documentation for the server to see if this is valid syntax?

Comment: You want a `where` clause. Except is for combining two queries, it's not a condition on which rows to process

Answer (score 1):

my guess you probably need something like

```
DELETE FROM Project.dbo.User WHERE UserName <> 'Administrator'
```

But that would depend on the schema of the User Table which isn't provided.

It seems like you are taking an object oriented approach thinking of Administrator as an object but in the database that would simply be a tuple (cell) in a row if it existed and you need to query the table to figure out all of the rows that you want to do the operation on.